# Android signing app fallback when keystore or property don't exist

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

My app has `signingConfigs` and I stored keystore file and `keystore.properties` on `app/.signing` which is gitignored. Therefore, when my teammates clone the repository, error occurs since `keystore.properties` does not exist.
This is my app level gradle settings.

```
File keystorePropertyFile = project.file('.signing/keystore.properties')
boolean useSigning = keystorePropertyFile.exists()
...
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (useSigning) {
                Properties properties = new Properties()
                properties.load(keystorePropertyFile.newDataInputStream())

                keyAlias properties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword properties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(properties['storeFile'])
                storePassword properties['storePassword']
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Gradle sync is OK, but when build APK the error occur saying **Keystore file not set for signing config release**

I want to sign app with android default debug key when the keystore or property file don't exist.

Comment: singing? like smule? :D

Comment: Oh, thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround. It was all about groovy.

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertyFile = project.file('.signing/keystore.properties')
def keyAliasProp, keyPasswordProp, storeFileProp, storePasswordProp
def hasKeyInfo = propertyFile.exists()

if (hasKeyInfo) {
    properties.load(propertyFile.newDataInputStream())

    def keystoreFile = file(properties['storeFile'])
    hasKeyInfo = keystoreFile.exists()

    if (hasKeyInfo) {
        keyAliasProp = properties['keyAlias']
        keyPasswordProp = properties['keyPassword']
        storeFileProp = keystoreFile
        storePasswordProp = properties['storePassword']
    }
}
...
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        if (hasKeyInfo) { // key part
            release {
                keyAlias keyAliasProp
                keyPassword keyPasswordProp
                storeFile storeFileProp
                storePassword storePasswordProp
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            if (hasKeyInfo) { // key part
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (hasKeyInfo) { // key part
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI, this works for debug build, you still need key  for release build.